# How can I retrieve IDFA and AAID in React Native using 'react-native-advertising-id' package?

Tags: typescript, react-native

Need help obtaining IDFA and AAID in React Native

I'm developing an application using React Native and I need to retrieve the IDFA (Identifier for Advertising) and AAID (Android Advertising ID) from the device.

I'm using the package "react-native-advertising-id" to access the identifiers. Here's the code I'm using:

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { getAdvertisingId } from "react-native-advertising-id";

export const useModal = (id, identity, open) => {
  const [idMobile, setIdMobile] = useState(null);

  const handleGetIDFAorAAID = useCallback(async () => {
    if (Platform.OS !== "android") return;

    try {
      const response = await getAdvertisingId();
      setIdMobile(response);
    } catch (error) {
      setIdMobile(null);
      console.error(error);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      handleGetIDFAorAAID();
    }
  }, [handleGetIDFAorAAID, open, idMobile]);
};
```

However, I'm facing difficulties in retrieving the identifiers. When executing the code, I'm getting a "TypeError: undefined is not a function" error. I'm sure I've properly installed the "react-native-advertising-id" package and followed all the setup instructions.

Additionally, I noticed that I'm using React Native 0.71.8 and TypeScript in my project.

I would like to know if there is any solution to obtain the IDFA and AAID in React Native using the "react-native-advertising-id" package. Am I making any mistakes in the code or is there a better alternative to access these identifiers on Android and iOS devices?

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!